# vs code terminal window show file location. In C-C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, terminal

I used to make basic program of C/C++ in vs code. After 2-3 weeks. in it's terminal it is not showing variable in output window. after making program when i run code.when i hit enter key it shows in terminal--it is not an error but code is not working.

PC C:\User\Owner\Desktop\C-C++>

WHEN I HIT ENTER IT AGAIN SHOW

PS C:\User\Owner\Desktop\C-C++>
IT DOES NOT SHOW 'ENTER VALUE OF B=='

IN THE TERMINAL OUTPUT WINDOW:-

for ex-:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int a, b, c;
   cout << "ENTER VALUE OF A==";
   cin >> a;
   cout << "ENTER VALUE OF B==";
   cin >> b;
   c = a + b;
   cout << "ADDITION OF VALUES" << c;
   return 0;
}
```

```
      IN THE TERMINAL WINDOW IT SHOWS.
       ENTER VALUE OF A==5                   ( WHEN I PRESS ENTER )
```

THEN IT SHOWS
PS C:\User\Owner\Desktop\C-C++>5
5
AGAIN
PS C:\User\Owner\Desktop\C-C++>

PLEASE ANSWER THIS PROBLEM :(

Comment: I fixed your code formatting problem. However I don't understand the question.

Comment: `cin >> a;` should be tested to ensure the program was able to parse the user input into an `int`. The program could be failing here and if you never check, you'll never know. In general, you should test every IO transaction and proceed on success or handle the error on failure.

Comment: No, In terminal output window it shows 'ENTER VALUE OF A==' when i give value to a and i press enter then it shows PC C:\User\Owner\Desktop\C-C++> rather than 'ENTER VALUE OF B==